# Kaminari Error for Rails Admin

Tags: rails-admin, kaminari

Hi, I have a Rails app that uses the Rails Admin gem.
When I click on the other links inside my Admin Page I get an error:

> > NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#index
> >
> > undefined method `page_method_name' for Kaminari::Configuration:0x007fe2c7ce75f0

Can you please help me figure out why am I getting this error? 
I'm using the kaminari and rails_admin gems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the master branch from this fork of the `kaminari` gem https://github.com/musicglue/kaminari.git. It contains a fix for this issue. I have the following in my Gemfile for the `kaminari` gem.

```
gem 'kaminari', git: 'https://github.com/musicglue/kaminari.git'
```